# Ubuntu software doesn't show any images of software

Tags: software-center

As you can see Ubuntu software doesn't show any images of software. How to fix that
[image]

But itself - program  icons are okay, and software installation as well
[image]

Tried, nothing changed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: I’d switch Ubuntu Software for GNOME Software. You can install it like this: sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade sudo apt install gnome-software
This GNOME Software loads the icons and I am able to install software with it.